# How to make this function return the coordinates instead of an empty list

Tags: prolog

I want the function to return the pairs (1, X) in a list when the position X in the two input lists is different but it keeps returning me an empty list.

```
propaga_posicoes_aux([], [], _, Pos, Pos).
propaga_posicoes_aux([X|Fila], [Y|N_Fila], (F1, F2), Pos, N_Pos):-
    F3 is F2 + 1,
    (((\+(compara_listas([X], [Y])),
    (append(N_Pos, [(F1, F2)] , N_Pos_aux))), 
    propaga_posicoes_aux(Fila, N_Fila, (F1, F3), N_Pos_aux, N_Pos_aux));
    propaga_posicoes_aux(Fila, N_Fila, (F1, F3), Pos, Pos)).
```

Here is a trace of when I run the function on the console:

```
[debug]  ?- propaga_posicoes_aux([1,1,1], [2,2,1], (1,1), [], N_P).
 T Call: (8) propaga_posicoes_aux([1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1],  (1, 1), [], _722)
 T Redo: (8) propaga_posicoes_aux([1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1],  (1, 1), [], _722)
 T Call: (9) propaga_posicoes_aux([1, 1], [2, 1],  (1, 2), [(1, 1)], [(1, 1)])
 T Redo: (9) propaga_posicoes_aux([1, 1], [2, 1],  (1, 2), [(1, 1)], [(1, 1)])
 T Call: (10) propaga_posicoes_aux([1], [1],  (1, 3), [(1, 1),  (1, 2)], [(1, 1),  (1, 2)])
 T Call: (11) propaga_posicoes_aux([], [],  (1, 4), [(1, 1),  (1, 2)], [(1, 1),  (1, 2)])
 T Exit: (11) propaga_posicoes_aux([], [],  (1, 4), [(1, 1),  (1, 2)], [(1, 1),  (1, 2)])
 T Exit: (10) propaga_posicoes_aux([1], [1],  (1, 3), [(1, 1),  (1, 2)], [(1, 1),  (1, 2)])
 T Exit: (9) propaga_posicoes_aux([1, 1], [2, 1],  (1, 2), [(1, 1)], [(1, 1)])
 T Exit: (8) propaga_posicoes_aux([1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1],  (1, 1), [], [])
N_P = [] .
```

As you can see the output is N_P = [], when I want it to be [(1,1),(1,2)].

What is the problem with my code here?

Comment: You `append/3` in the wrong way, here you append `N_Pos` and `[(F1, F2)]` to `N_Pos_aux`, probably you want to do it the opposite way around.

Comment: First problem: say `listing(propaga_posicoes_aux)` to see how this code is usually indented to ease reading. I'm no parser not.

Comment: Doing the append the other way arround just makes the function return true instead of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code. I am too lazy to debug it for you :-(

You don't need `append/3` at all. `append/3` is very useful, but only when it's useful. When it's not useful then it's useless.

Don't use `(a, b)` for pairs. It is silly. Use `a-b`.

And why use a pair if the first element is always the same?

A predicate that succeeds if the first and second argument are lists of the same length and the third argument is the list of indices (1-based) where the corresponding elements of the first and second arguments are not the same.

```
dif_ns(Xs, Ys, Ns) :-
    dif_ns(Xs, Ys, 1, Ns).

dif_ns([], [], _, []).
dif_ns([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], N, [N|Ns]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    succ(N, N1),
    dif_ns(Xs, Ys, N1, Ns).
dif_ns([X|Xs], [X|Ys], N, Ns) :-
    succ(N, N1),
    dif_ns(Xs, Ys, N1, Ns).
```

There is a bit of code duplication between the second and third clause of the helper predicate, and an unnecessary choice point. You can [get fancy and use library(reif)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/).

```
:- use_module(reif).

dif_ns(Xs, Ys, Ns) :-
    dif_ns(Xs, Ys, 1, Ns).

dif_ns([], [], _, []).
dif_ns([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], N, Ns) :-
    succ(N, N1),
    if_(X = Y, Ns = Ns0, Ns = [N|Ns0]),
    dif_ns(Xs, Ys, N1, Ns0).
```

Once you have the indices, you can make pairs from these.